# ngModel vs keyup/down

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

while learning angular2, came across these two ways to read value from input field as below,

```
<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="pname"> // I can read the value from --> pname
<input type="text" (keyup)="addvalue($event)"> // I can check for enter press and read text
```

For ex, if I want to write a ToDo app and ask user to enter the list in input field, post clicking `Add` button, could add it in list

`keyup` will trigger the method for each keypress, won't it affect the performance?

please explain the scenarios when to use `[(ngModel)]` and `keyup`

Answer (score 1):

Use ngModel when you want two way binding: setting a default value and getting any changes to that value.

Use keyup when you what to watch the keys the user types, such as watching for entry of a return key.

Comment: I don't want two way binding. if I want to take the value user entered and add it to the list, which one should I go for??

Comment: If you don't care about tracking key strokes or watching for particular keys, then use ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="pname">`

angular will internally convert [(ngModel)] into

```
<input [ngModel]="pname" (ngModelChange)="pname= $event">
```

> The property binding [ngModel] takes care of updating the underlying
>   input DOM element. The event binding (ngModelChange) notifies the
>   component calss(.ts File) when there was a change in the DOM